# How to log every message in new line using winston logger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

we are using winston logger to log events to nodejs `fs` , i want to write every event into new line using winston, is it possible with to achieve that task using winston library or any other approach that works with nodejs.

ctrl.js

```
var winston = require('winston');
var consumer = new ConsumerGroup(options, topics);
        console.log("Consumer topics:", getConsumerTopics(consumer).toString());
        logger = new (winston.Logger)({
            level: null,
            transports: [
//                new (winston.transports.Console)(),
                new (winston.transports.File)({
                    filename: './logs/st/server.log',
                    maxsize: 1024 * 1024 * 20,//15728640 is 15 MB
                    timestamp: false,
                    json: false,
                    formatter: function (options) {
                        return options.message;
                    }
                })
            ]
        });
        function startConsumer(consumer) {
            consumer.on('message', function (message) {
                logger.log('info', message.value);
                //callback(message.value);
                io.io().emit('StConsumer', message.value);
            });
            consumer.on('error', function (err) {
                console.log('error', err);
            });
        };
        startConsumer(consumer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this, using the `split` module:

```
const split = require('split');
const winston = require('winston');

winston.emitErrs = false;

const logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
      level: 'debug',
      filename: 'server.log',
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: false,
      maxsize: 5242880,
      maxFiles: 5,
      colorize: false,
      timestamp: true,
    }),
    new winston.transports.Console({
      level: 'debug',
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: false,
      colorize: true,
      timestamp: true,
    }),
  ],
  exitOnError: false,
});

logger.stream = split().on('data', message => logger.info(message));

module.exports = logger;
```

It works pretty well for my needs by your mileage may vary.

The `split` module:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/split

Comment: so in my case i can do `logger.stream = split().on('data',message,function(message){message.value})`  sorry i am not familiar with ES6 yet

Comment: @hussain No. This: `logger.stream = split().on('data', message => logger.info(message));` is equivalent with this: `logger.stream = split().on('data', function (message) { logger.info(message); });`

Comment: but i see its not writing to `fs` with this approach

Comment: @hussain It is writing to the the file system - to file `server.log` in my example. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: yes i tried it its not writing to  `server.log` thats why i asked another question if i can do something in `fs` once i log data split based on event

Comment: i just change  this line `//logger.log('info', message.value);` to 
               ` logger.stream = split().on('data', function (message) { logger.info(message); });` i dont see any error